# Datatool (datagidx) index with special characters

Tags: beamer, indexing, datatool

When I define multiple terms that contain an underscore and begin with the same string ex_ 1, ex_ 2 (as shown in the example below) I get the following error:

> ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].  
>                      \expandafter  l.30     \end{frame}

However, when I define the term e2 using the commented out line below (e2_ 2) it compiles fine. If I just remove the escaped underscores (see below) that works as well. Can someone tell me how to work around this?

```
\documentclass[16pt,pdftex]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
% beamer doesn't define \@idxitem, but it's used by the
% \printterms "index" style, so define it:
\newcommand\@idxitem{\par\hangindent40pt}
\makeatother

\usepackage{datagidx}

\newgidx{index}{Index}
\DTLgidxSetDefaultDB{index}

% this fails:
 \newterm[label=e1]{ex\_ 1}
 \newterm[label=e2]{ex\_ 2}

% this works
%\newterm[label=e1]{ex\_ 1}
%\newterm[label=e2]{e2\_ 2}

% this works
%\newterm[label=e1]{ex 1}
%\newterm[label=e2]{ex 2}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{example}
\gls{e1}
\gls{e2}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{Index}
\printterms[style=index]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As it says in the documentation, you can't use active characters in the label. Do you really need an underscore in your label? (After all, it's only an identifier not typeset material.)

Comment: I'm a little confused here. In this example:
\newterm[label=e1]{ex\_ 1}

Isn't the label 'e1' and the text/term that contains the active character ('ex\\_ 1')?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. I think the problem is the mechanism that sets the default sort value. Try `\newterm[label=e1,sort={ex1}]{ex\_ 1}`

Comment: That's it, and I think it makes sense as well. Thanks, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second comment by Nicola Talbot answered my question: Without specifying a sort option it tries to sort by the term and when the sorter gets to the escape character it has a hard time. Specifying the sort option:

```
\newterm[label=e1,sort={ex1}]{ex\_ 1}
\newterm[label=e2,sort={ex2}]{ex\_ 2}
```

Solves the problem for me.